# R: Automatically save plots from multiple devices

Tags: r

I am working with double hierarchical generalized linear models in R and I would like to save the diagnostic plots of the models for later inspection. As I run several models in a loop fashion, I need an automated solution for this. 
Below I bring an example,

```
library(hglm)
y<-rnorm(1000)
A<-sample(1:5,1000,replace=TRUE)
B<-sample(1:3,1000,replace=TRUE)
X<-model.matrix(~A)
Z<-model.matrix(~B)
model<-hglm(y=y,X=X,Z=Z,X.disp=X)
```

To get the diagnostic plots, I write the command as in generalized linear models,

```
plot(model)
```

but, in this specific case, I obtain the plots in four separate devices. The problem is I cannot save them all. I have tried the regular operations,

```
pdf('Test plots from multiple devices.pdf')
plot(model)
dev.off()
```

But nothing is printed into the file. I have also tried

```
pdf('Test plots from multiple devices.pdf')
print(plot(model))
dev.off()
```

Does not work either. I have then tried to save each window at a time in a single file by selecting the different devices before saving. Given that device 1 is the null.device, the plots appear in devices 2 to 5. Therefore, I did this,

```
pdf('Test plots from multiple devices 1.pdf')
dev.set(2)
dev.off()

pdf('Test plots from multiple devices 2.pdf')
dev.set(3)
dev.off()

pdf('Test plots from multiple devices 3.pdf')
dev.set(4)
dev.off()

pdf('Test plots from multiple devices 4.pdf')
dev.set(5)
dev.off()
```

Same result. Nothing changes if I print the selections either, for instance,

```
pdf('Test plots from multiple devices 1.pdf')
print(dev.set(2))
dev.off()
```

Hope you know how to do this.
Thanks a lot! All the best.

Comment: Could you share the platform, version, etc you are using?
In my hands, your first example worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is really odd. I am working with RGui 3.0.3 and the platform is x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library has it's own custom plot function that doesn't behave in the same way as "standard" plotting functions. If you check out the

```
?plot.hglm
```

help page. You'll see that there is a `device=` parameter. Try something like

```
plot(model, device="pdf", name="TestPlots.pdf")
```

Otherwise, if you want to copy the content from existing device, you can do something like this. After running

```
plot(model)
```

you'll probably get something like

```
dev.list()
# windows windows windows windows 
#       2       3       4       5
```

Then, to copy the contents to one of those devices, you can do

```
pdf("out.pdf")
dx <- dev.cur()
dev.set(2)
dev.copy(which=dx)
dev.set(dx)
dev.off()
```

to copy device 2 for example.

To save all open graphical devices to the same pdf, you can set up a loop like

```
open.dev <- dev.list()
pdf("ok.pdf")
dx <- dev.cur()
for(d in open.dev) {
    dev.set(d)
    dev.copy(which=dx)
}
dev.set(dx)
dev.off()
```

And one last option, you can use this helper function

```
dev.copyfrom <- function(from, to=dev.cur()) {
    stopifnot(from %in% dev.list())
    stopifnot(from!=to)
    dx <- dev.cur()
    dev.set(from)
    dev.copy(which=to)
    dev.set(dx)
}
```

which would copy the contents from a particular device to the current (or other) specified device). Then you can do

```
pdf("out1.pdf")
dev.copyfrom(2)
dev.off()
pdf("out2.pdf")
dev.copyfrom(3)
dev.off()
```

and so on if you want different files for each.

Comment: The first approach works great, yet it is also great to know the others, thanks a lot @MrFlick! Just one thing, at least in my version and platform you do not need to write the file extension after you specify the type of device you want to save. In your example, you can just write `plot(model, device="pdf", name="TestPlots")` and in HGLMs it will save four files, from TestPlots1.pdf to TestPlots4.pdf .